# Display logout menu after login from another component?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I want to enable display the logout button after login from `detailed-page.component.ts`. The Join Us/Logout menu is in header compoent.

This is i have tried. But after login not enable the logout menu. How to fix this issue?.

**header.component.html**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                                       
     <li class="loginmenu joinusmenu" (click)="showmodel('register');" *ngIf="loginStatus==0" ><span>Join Us</span></li>
     <li class="loginmenu joinusmenu" (click)="logout();" *ngIf="loginStatus==1"><span>Logout</span></li>
</ul>
```

**detailed-page.component.ts**

```
constructor(

    private headerComponent: HeaderComponent

) {}

login() {

    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.lpassword)
        .subscribe(
                data => {
                this.headerComponent.loginStatus= 1;
                })
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    @Component({ 
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <app-header></app-header>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>    
        <app-footer></app-footer>`,
      styleUrls: ['../app/app.component.css'],
    })

    export class AppComponent { 

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you won't be needing to do much state management you could use a very simple service like this.  Basically this StoreService would contain all data that needs to be shared across all components:

```
export class StoreService {
  public loginStatus = 0; // 0 = not logged in, 1 = logged in

  setLoginStatus(status: number) {
    this.loginStatus = status;
  }
}
```

This would then get injected into your head and detailed component like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detailed',
  template: `
 <button *ngIf="store.loginStatus === 0" (click)="login()">Login</button>
`,
})
export class DetailedComponent {
  constructor(public store: StoreService) {
  }

  login() {
    this.store.setLoginStatus(1);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  template: `
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                                       
       <li class="loginmenu joinusmenu" (click)="showmodel('register')" *ngIf="store.loginStatus==0" ><span>Join Us</span></li>
       <li class="loginmenu joinusmenu" (click)="logout()" *ngIf="store.loginStatus==1"><span>Logout</span></li>
  </ul>
`,
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(public store: StoreService) {
  }

  showmodel() {
  }

  logout() {
    this.store.setLoginStatus(0);
  }
}
```

Here's a working plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/xBnWAP7EacoIc5j3USQv?p=preview

Note that the StoreService doesn't scale for applications that need to a lot of modifications to the shared state.  For a more scalable solution look into using ngrx.

Comment: its working fine. but when i build the app i got this error `ERROR in D:/xampp/htdocs/angular2/src/$$_gendir/app/header/header.component.ngfactory.ts (10238,45): 
Property 'authenticationService' is private and only accessible within class 'HeaderComponent'.`

Comment: Is your authenticationService in its own file?  If not try putting it in its own file and make sure to register it in the module file's providers array.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6108 
According to this it appears to be related to AOT compilation.  As a quick easy verification you can try to do ng build -prod --aot=false to see if cli will let you build.

Comment: i have changed `private` to `public` in `constructor(public authenticationService: authenticationService)`. is this fine?.  that is the issue. now working fine. Thanks you so much for your help.